# how to create inherited table in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables called `Parent` and `Child`. I am using oracle to create these tables. Child table inherits from parent. How to create this inherited child table in oracle without creating types.

I want relevant oracle statement for following PostgreSQL create tables.

```
Create Table Parent
(
    .....
)

Create Table Child
(
    .....
)INHERITS (Parent);
```

Comment: this is a design question. you can create a "header" table with all the similar columns and a "child" tables with the details for each type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oracle does not support inheritance by tables - it uses TYPEs (objects) instead.  The way to do something like this in Oracle would be to declare the Parent TYPE and the Child TYPE, then create a table to contain instances of PARENT - something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PARENT AS OBJECT (...);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CHILD UNDER PARENT (...);

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE OF PARENT;
```

Since CHILD is a sub-type of PARENT it should be possible to store CHILD instances in the PEOPLE table.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

yes it seems to work as in postgres table inheritance with the solution mentioned above, e.g.

```
DROP TABLE PEOPLE1;
DROP TABLE PEOPLE2;
DROP TYPE CHILD1;
DROP TYPE CHILD2;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE commun AS OBJECT (c1 integer, C2 date) NOT FINAL
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CHILD1 UNDER PARENT (c3 varchar2(20), c4 number(8,2))
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CHILD2 UNDER PARENT (c5 number(5,2), c6 varchar2(10))
/

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE1 OF CHILD1;
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE2 OF CHILD2;

insert into people1 values (1, sysdate, 'ABCDE', 3.14);
insert into people1 values (2, sysdate, 'FGGHJK', 2.24);

insert into people2 values (3, sysdate, 1.14, 'test');
insert into people2 values (4, sysdate, 8.24 , 'test1');

desc people1
desc people2

select * from people1;
select * from people2;
```