# how to create a table that inherits from another table in SQL 3?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this table salle that has 2 attributes
this is the table that inherits from salle, it's called salleCours and has 3 additional attributes.
when i run the second command in oracle 11g express in sql command line it says under 'under' : missing or invalid option.
i dont know if it's a syntax problem or something else

```
Create table salle(
Numero varchar(20) primary key,
Videoprojecteur char(1) ) ;
Create table salleCours UNDER salle(
Capacite number(3),
Retroprojecteur char(1),
micro char(1)) ;
```

Comment: What does it mean, that "salleCours inherits from salle"? Inherits what? As far as I can tell, there's no UNDER in Oracle (at least, not in this context). Where did you take that syntax from? What are you trying to do? And, what is "SQL 3"?

Comment: Searching around, it seems like "CREATE TABLE ... UNDER" is a feature of IBM Informix and DB/2. PostgreSQL also has a concept of "table inheritance", but it uses a different syntax ("CREATE TABLE ... INHERITS"), and I've no idea if the semantics are the same as IBM's "sub-tables".

Comment: Searching for "oracle table inheritance" turned up this question, with a suggested alternative in the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17512871/157957

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60938760/1509264

Answer (score 0):

You want to define an `OBJECT` type and then use an object-defined table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE salle_type AS OBJECT(
  Numero          varchar(20),
  Videoprojecteur char(1)
) NOT FINAL;

CREATE TYPE salleCours_type UNDER salle_type(
  Capacite number(3),
  Retroprojecteur char(1),
  micro char(1)
);

CREATE TABLE salle OF salle_type (
  Numero PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Then you can insert rows of either type:

```sql
INSERT INTO salle VALUES( salle_type( 'abc', 'Y' ) );
INSERT INTO salle VALUES( salleCours_type( 'def', 'Y', 42, 'N', 'X' ) );
```

And, if you want the values:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       TREAT( VALUE(s) AS salleCours_type ).Capacite AS capacite,
       TREAT( VALUE(s) AS salleCours_type ).Retroprojecteur AS Retroprojecteur,
       TREAT( VALUE(s) AS salleCours_type ).micro AS micro
FROM   salle s
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> NUMERO | VIDEOPROJECTEUR | CAPACITE | RETROPROJECTEUR | MICRO
> :----- | :-------------- | -------: | :-------------- | :----
> abc    | Y               |     null | null            | null 
> def    | Y               |       42 | N               | X
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4a973211bc72ed58ebc3ce0f81dbf66)*